# Create a hash from a ParameterMap object

Tags: java, hash

i have objects X and Y of class Container.
Both are asociated to a ParameterMap object, wich is a map String-String (request parameter values).
let be:

```
X exampleX;
Y exampleY;
```

I want to know if exampleX is asociated with the same ParameterMap as exampleY.
As i dont really need the value of the map, i thought i could store in class Container a integer, the result of  hash function to the parameterMap which the object is asociated.
So, if X.parameterMapHash == Y.parameterMapHash, then the maps have the same values for the same keys....

Is this a good approach? How can i make this in java? i need something to make a hash from a object...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `==` to determine if two variables reference the same object.

```
if (X.parameterMapHash == Y.parameterMapHash)
{
    //they reference the same object
    //doSomething
}
```

However, if you're asking how to figure out if two `Maps` are entirely equivalent, but do not necessairly reference the same object, then you could do something like:

```
boolean checkKeysAndValues()  
{  
    if(X.parameterHashMap.size() == Y.parameterHashMap.size())
    {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : X.parameterHashMap.entrySet())
        {
            if (!(Y.ParameterHashMap.containsKey(entry.getKey()) &&
                Y.ParameterHashMap.get(entry.getKey()).equals(entry.getValue()))
            {            
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```